# Can I detect the presence of a physical keyboard in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to display a message on my site that says "Press F11 to enter full screen mode", but I only want to display this message if the user has a physical keyboard attached.

Is this possible?

Comment: in short No. you need something at kernel level.

Comment: I don't think "kernel level" and JavaScript have too much overlap lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On top of my head, Javascript does not have a method to check if a physical keyboard is attached. You need to do something in deer level. Instead, I can suggest you two options if you have to check that in JS.

1. Ask users

```
if (confirm('Do you have a physical keyboard attached?') {
  // do something
}
```

2. You can check if touch screen is enabled

```
if ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't love either of these options, but maybe I am out of luck.

I am going to leave this unanswered for a little while longer, to see if anyone offers another creative solution. If not, I'll come back and mark your response as the accepted answer.